# Custom syntax highlighting in sublime text 3

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Hello I'm developing a [Maze](https://github.com/Mimieam/Sublime-Maze) game/plugin for ST3 and I'm trying to add some colors to unicode characters and square brackets.
After [some](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) reading I figured out most of what i needed to do (tmLanguage file and syntax)

What I'm still not understanding is where do I had a custom hex color ?

here is what I've tried but without success:

First in maze.tmLanguage

```
<key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>comment</key>
            <string>This pattern matches the walls of the maze</string>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>\[\]</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>entity.wall.mzl</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>fontStyle</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#BADA55</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>comment</key>
            <string>This pattern matches the player charactere</string>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>[\u25C4,\u25BA,\u25B2,\u25BC]</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>entity.player.mzl</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
```

Then in 
Walker.py

```
        #load the maze color syntax
        self.view.set_syntax_file("Packages/Walker/maze.tmLanguage")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.tmLanguage` file only contains the regexes to define the scopes. It's up to the color scheme's `.tmTheme` file to assign a color to the scope. You need to remove the settings and put it in your theme of choice. Read a few of the `.tmLanguage` files included with Sublime Text 2 (in `Packages/LanguageName/LanguageName.tmLanguage`, they're easier to get at than the ones in ST3) and look through a couple of `.tmTheme` files in the `Packages/Color Schemes - Default` directory to get an idea of what goes where. As it is now, your XML is a mixture of both.

Comment: ok i added a .tmThme file but it override my default theme for all my files, i would like to just target a file with extension *.mzl

Comment: take whatever content you put in your new `.tmTheme` file and just add it to an existing theme of your choice. Themes are "all or nothing" - you can't have multiple ones active at the same time.

Comment: turns out it is possible to do just that, now I just have to figure out how to get the unicode characters colored, thank you for pointing me in the right direction